# How to debug shape mismatch of theano tensor?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, theano

I defined a Theano tensor `m = T.imatrix('m')` and used it as an argument of a theano function `foo`.

When I now call `foo(arr)` with a numpy array `arr` of shape (100,3), I'd expect that `m[:, 1]` would have the shape (100,).

However, the error message shows that the shape is (1,100). How can I examine the function mismatch step by step?

Comment: Given your description, `foo(arr).shape` ought to be `(100,)`, since `m[:, 1]` will be a 1D slice of `m`. If your output is `(100, 1)` then there must be an additional mistake in your code.

Comment: Oh, indeed, so there seems to be another issue somewhere. So theano tensors act like numpy arrays, isn't it?

Comment: Theano indexing is similar (but not identical) to numpy indexing. [See here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#indexing).

Comment: Is there any way to evaluate the shape easy in debugging. Currently I am just reading the "Input dimension mis-match" error message

Comment: For debugging purposes I usually write a bunch of throw-away functions for evaluating intermediate symbolic variables. This way you can figure out where in your computation you are ending up with an incorrectly shaped tensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the useful hints in the comments I was able to debug the shape mismatch. I set up another theano debug function with the same inputs and a custom output, which I could examine with the debugger, e.g.:

```
# define a function ...
inputs = T.matrix('inputs')
debug_out = T.sum(fancy_expression(inputs)) # expression to debug
debug_fn = theano.function(
        inputs=[inputs], 
        outputs=debug_out,
        on_unused_input='ignore' # to suppress unused input exeptions
)

# ... and debug it here
result = debug_fn(np.empty((100,3)))
```

Thanks again to @ali_m

Comment: Is the above actually correct?  I get `name 'debug_out' is not defined` as an error, and what's the role of the `np.empty((100, 3))` there?

Comment: @RobertP.Goldman ``out`` should have been ``debug_out``. I've fixed that now. The numpy array is the input that your function you want to debug receives. It will be 'fed' into the computation graph for the ``inputs`` variable